# Outlook Drag and Drop - ActiveExplorer().Selection() doesn't contain all items

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

In my Outlook add-in, I'm attempting to obtain information on all items that are dragged and dropped by the user into a MAPI store (I'm using the Redemption library).

My first attempt at this has been to hook into the MessageCreated event...

```
myRDOStore.OnMessageCreated += new IRDOStoreEvents_OnMessageCreatedEventHandler(myRDOStore_OnMessageCreated);
```

The tricky part is that I need to capture all items which are dragged and dropped at the same time as one collection, which I guess means persisting some aspect of each new message that comes in (probably the EntryId).

Now, the problem is clearly that I have no way of tying the results of a bunch of arbitrary events together, so I was looking into the `ActiveExplorer().Selection` collection and trying to think of ways of determine which items had been dragged and dropped into my stored from that.

I didn't have much luck with that, as the contents of the collection seemed a bit haphazard (e.g. when dragging 1 item, there would be two items in `Selection` when I examined it in the event handler, or when a series of events fired there would be e.g. 2 items in Selection, then 1 on the next event, then 1 in the next etc).

In addition to that, one of my use cases is the ability to drag items from outside Outlook, which I'm guessing would not be included in the `Selection` collection.

Are there any standard approaches to this problem? It seems like something that would be quite common - to drag a bunch of files into a folder and be able to obtain some information on them as a collection, but I just can't figure it out. Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Try narrowing your question down to a specific use case instead of trying to solve all your drag-n-drop problems with one post. Clearly explain where you are dragging from (*Outlook, WPF, WinForms, Explorer, etc.*) and where you are dragging to - it's hard to follow. Identifying the source and target will make it easier for us to provide you with guidance.

Comment: @SliverNinja: Apologies, I was in a bit of a hurry when writing my post. My sources were both Outlook and Explorer, and my target is Outlook. I've actually come up with a solution that I'm fairly happy with using a timer. I'll post the code up when I get a chance in case it's useful to anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found that the problem is that the dropped emails COM objects aren't being released. The easiest way to release them is to call the e.Data.GetData("RenPrivateMessages"); method after finishing the drag and drop logic in the DragDrop Event Handler.